# passing DOMElement in a function

Tags: xsd

Can i pass the DOMelement in a function..
for example..

```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
    $doc->load('Sample_SGL-3-1.xsd');
    $xsdstring = "Sample_SGL-3-1.xsd";
    $t = new XMLREADER();
    $t->open($xsdstring);
    $complex=$doc->getElementsByTagName("complexType");
    foreach($complex as $c)
        {
            $com_name=$c->getAttribute("name");
            $com_min=$c->getAttribute("minOccurs");
            $com_max=$c->getAttribute("maxOccurs");
                    if(some condition)
                    {
                      echo '<input type="button" onClick="addComplexType()">';
                    }
         }
```

How can I pass this $c in OnClick function

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear, what function is there?  You can pass anything in a function.

Comment: There is a function in javascript,and this $c is a dom object,whenever m passing this in the function addComplexType,it is giving error like,object cannot be converted to string.What is the possible way.

To be more precise,how to do this
echo '<input type="button" onClick="addComplexType($c)">';

as doing this is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification in the comments, you want to pass a PHP DOMElement into a JavaScript function.

The short answer is no you can not do that directly.

What you could do is add an ID attribute to the, and then in JavaScript fetch that element by ID.